# Interceptor Plugin for Product Attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, plugin, interceptor

I'm trying to modify the "short_description" attribute using a plugin but I can't seem to get it to work across the whole website. I can do this on the product view page with the following but I don't know how to do this globally across the whole website.

I've been trying to create a plugin on "getAttributes" but nothing I try wants to work.

**../app/code/TM/Customplugin/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
        <plugin name="tm-block-plugin" type="TM\Customplugin\Plugin\GetProductPlugin" sortOrder="2" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**../app/code/TM/Customplugin/Plugin/GetProductPlugin.php**

```
<?php
    namespace TM\Customplugin\Plugin;
    class GetProductPlugin
    {    
        public function afterGetProduct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $subject, $result)
        {
            $result['short_description'] = strtolower($result['short_description']);
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This product attribute is being called through the helper class

`$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description')`.

Using `print_r(get_class_methods($_helper))` I get this:

`Array ( [0] => __construct [1] => addHandler [2] => getHandlers [3] => process [4] => productAttribute [5] => categoryAttribute [6] => isDirectivesExists [7] => isModuleOutputEnabled )`

Does anyone know if I need to create a plugin to intercept the productAttribute from the helper or is there another way?

**SOLUTION**

I ended up getting this to work using the preference class rewrite method and not the Plugin method. I know this isn't ideal but it works. If anyone knows how to achieve the same result using a Plugin please share :)

**/app/code/TM/Module1/etc/di.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="TM\Module1\Model\Catalog\Product" />
    </config>
```

**/app/code/TM/Module1/Model/Catalog/Product.php**

```
<?php
namespace TM\Module1\Model\Catalog;
class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{    
    public function getShortDescription()
    {        
        return strtolower($this['short_description']);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using is only valid for product detail page.

You can do it by adding plugin on class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` with method `afterGetShortDescription()`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Yash, I tried that but I still can't get it to work :(

**Here's what I have but it's not showing up in the log**
`public function beforeGetShortDescription(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
  return strtolower($result);
  
  $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('It is from DemoOverridePlugin '.__METHOD__ . ' line - ' . __LINE__);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

1) Create this file in `app/code/Solwin/Module1/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
            <plugin name="sl-block-plugin" type="Solwin\Module1\Plugin\GetShortDescPlugin"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

2) Create this file in `app/code/Solwin/Module1/Plugin/GetShortDescPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace Solwin\Module1\Plugin;
class GetShortDescPlugin
{
   public function afterGetShortDescription(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
   {
       $result['short_description'] = strtolower($result['short_description']);
            return $result;
    }  
}
?>
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. As far as I can tell the GetShortDescription method isn't the default method used by Magento. In the template files it uses the helper class 

`$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description')`

...so I think I need to create a plugin that accesses `productAttribute` from within the `$_helper` class. 

I've Googled this for days and can't seem to find any answers :(