# Magento2 product meta title and description

Tags: magento-2.1, product, meta-title, meta-description

Use magento2.1
Need to generate meta title and description for my products dynamically, forexample: BASEURL-for your(Static string)-Product title, and for meta description example: static string-attribute1-attribute2

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304881/interceptor-plugin-for-product-attributes/304884#304884

Comment: It is not work on meta title and meta description

Answer (score 0):

I just override

**File: module-catalog/Block/Category/View.php**

And add the below code. I am just providing you a logic. I have directly used a custom query. I have created a table to add URL, title, description, and keyword then I have matched current URL in the table and then set title, description, and keyword dramatically.

```
$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
        $current_url = $urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();

        if ($current_url)
        {
            $sqlQueryCustom_url_meta_data= "SELECT * FROM custom_url_meta_data where url='".$current_url."'";
            $resultCustom_url_meta_data=$connection->fetchAll($sqlQueryCustom_url_meta_data);
            if($resultCustom_url_meta_data)
            {
                $title = $resultCustom_url_meta_data[0]['meta_title'];
                $description = $resultCustom_url_meta_data[0]['meta_description'];
                $keywords = $resultCustom_url_meta_data[0]['meta_keywords'];
                $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title);
                $this->pageConfig->setDescription($description);
                $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($keywords);
            }
        }
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks, could you please let me know how can i set sample static strings into this code?

Comment: you can directly set string to $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set('title test'); $this->pageConfig->setDescription('description test'); $this->pageConfig->setKeywords('keyword test');